# What are Best Practices for Maven Modules Naming?

Tags: maven-2, naming, convention

Assuming that we have a project named `project` and modules `module1` and `module2`, earlier I tend to use the following naming strategy:

```
-- project
  -- projectModule1
  -- projectModule2
```

Now I use another:

```
-- project
  -- project-module1
  -- project-module2
```

What are best practices for Maven modules naming?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I wrote some notes on this in the "Effective Implementation" book, but there is no rule or canonical convention.

To summarise some:

First of all, the most important things is that you are consistent.

General Maven convention uses '-' as the separator (`commons-lang`, `maven-model`).

If you intend for it to be used externally, remember the `module = artifact ID = filename` (in best practice), so it needs to be recognisable (`maven-model-2.0.jar` is clear, `model-2.0.jar` is not). In this case, you usually repeat the last element of the group ID as a mini-namespace. "Internal" modules may omit it for brevity (As the example application shows: http://github.com/brettporter/centrepoint/tree/master/centrepoint/modules/).

Aside from that, I'd keep them as short as possible.

You might draw the parallel between Java package and class naming conventions to Maven group and artifact IDs.

Answer (score 5):

I usually try to keep module names brief. If the name 'wants' to be long, that's an indication that another nesting level is probably a good idea. So instead of this:

```
- root
    - api
    - impl
    - security
    - service-soap
    - service-rest
    - client-swing
    - client-web-html
    - client-web-mobile
```

I'd nest things further:

```
- root
    - api
    - impl
    - security
    - service
        - soap
        - rest
    - client
        - swing
        - web
            - html
            - mobile
```

through maven reactor options you can still build the nested modules isolated from the top:

```
mvn -pl client/web clean install
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even go one step further:

```
-- project
  -- project-module-1
  -- project-module-2
```

No joking now, this is really a question of taste.

Have a nice day Maksim

Comment: Good suggestion.
However, in this naming strategy I would prefer to reserve "-" character for separating nested modules. So "project-module-1" would mean that there is parent project "project", which has  a child project "module", which has a child project "1".

Comment: Then project-module_1 would do the job.